# Вылетает ошибка при загрузке изображения

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В моей функции я использую itemconfig, чтобы поменять картинку на канвасе, однако в консоль вываливается ошибка:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "cheese.gif" doesn't exist
```

Файл существует, я проверил. Пробовал и слэши при написании путя к файлу обратные писать, и "r" - строки использовать. Вот моя функция:

```
def anim():
    image_2 = r'attack.gif'
    game.itemconfig(ball, image = image_2)
    return

root.after(20, anim)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Покажите ваш путь. Может там пробелы, русские буквы или ещё что-то, требующее особого внимания?

Comment: путь "attack.gif", а пробелы и прочее это первое что я проверил

Comment: image_2 = r'attack.gif'

Comment: Я имею в виду полны путь. Вы же сами пишете про путь к файлу, а теперь даёте название файла вообще без пути. Возможно, у скрипта текущий каталог стоит не тот, что вы думаете, хорошо бы напечатать в скрипте текущий путь.

Comment: C:\Users\Windows\Documents\Версии N-Text.exe\Zeugs\attack.gif, а вообще эта гифка лежит в той же папке что и питоновский файл

Comment: попробовал с полным путем, та же ошибка

Comment: Ага, ну вот и пробелы, и русские буквы. Для начала напечатайте всё же текущий каталог для вашего исполняющегося скрипта: `import os`
`print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: рабочий каталог нужный

Comment: А вы уверены, что там можно просто дать название файла, а не надо загружать сам image в некий объект самостоятельно и передавать в itemconfig именно объект со считанным уже image, а не название файла? Как вы до этого image задавали объекту ball?

Comment: передавал вот так: load = Image.open("attack.gif")
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load), но со вторым изображением - та-же ошибка